# IONIC3 for IOS Error - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'attrib' of null

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

When i try to create a build or run the ios version of my app by navigating to the root folder and passing the command:

```
sudo ionic cordova build ios --verbose
```

I am getting errors stating " UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'attrib' of null at ConfigParser.shortName "

Kindly help i am stuck with this from past 2 weeks. My Android build & Web Version works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing and adding the IOS platform again.

```
ionic cordova platform remove ios
ionic cordova platform add ios
```